# How To pass Array value in Ajax Parameter from Client side To Server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

```
$('#SendEmail').click(function () {
         var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (_, el) {
             return $(el).val();
         }).get();

         alert(sel);
         SetCompanyDetailsPopUp(sel);
     })
```

I have multiple Check box in forloop and Iam getting the value at Onclick Function "SendEmail " and Also calling the Ajax method,The  Ajax method "SetCompanyDetailsPopUp"is also working fine , but Parameter at server side is showing "null"

```
function SetCompanyDetailsPopUp(Email) {

         debugger;
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             async: false,
             dataType: "json",
             url: "/CRMLogin/GeneratePass",
             data: { "id": Value },
             success: function (result) {
                 var data = '';

                 alert(result);
                 //alert(result);
                 //alert('sucessfully generated');
             }
         });
     }
```

after Debugging Ajax Function The value in the "Email" parameter is

Array(2)
0:"1"
1:"2"
length:2
**proto**
:
Array(0)

serverside method

```
public ActionResult GeneratePass(string id)
{
   string[] arr = id.Split(','); ; // Initialize.

   // Loop over strings.
   foreach (string s in arr)
   {
       forgotPassword(s);
   }

    return Json(arr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: Is `alert(sel);` giving you comma separated email values???

Comment: yes it is separated by comma , I think That is the reason it is not taking the value

Comment: If it already has a comma separated values, then change `{ "id": Value }` to `{ "id": Email }`

Answer (score 0):

the issue from my point of view is that you don't have 
[FromBody] attribute in your controller method which is needed in Post methods
please check the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

So the Code should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GeneratePass([FromBody] string id)
    {
        string[] arr = id.Split(','); ; // Initialize.

    // Loop over strings.
    foreach (string s in arr)
    {
        forgotPassword(s);
    }


    return Json(arr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting The Value When I pass varchar at client , but when the value is in Array I am not getting the Value at Client

Comment: Is there Anyway that we can pass Array value to Ajax Parameters

Comment: if you try to pass string[] or the other way is to pass concatenated string

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the" traditional: true "
"ajax option to post back an array to the collection

```
    function SetCompanyDetailsPopUp(Email) {

     debugger;
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         async: false,
         dataType: "json",
         url: "/CRMLogin/GeneratePass",
         data: { "id": Email},
         traditional: true,       //Need to Add This
         success: function (result) {
             var data = '';

             alert(result);

         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not give the attribute [httppost] to the method. But your ajax is post type. Here is the code sample that work as expected.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        function SetCompanyDetailsPopUp(Email) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/CRMLogin/GeneratePass",
                data: { "id": Email },
                success: function (result) {
                    var data = '';
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }

        $('#SendEmail').click(function () {
            var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (_, el) {
                return $(el).val();
            }).get();
            SetCompanyDetailsPopUp(sel);
        });
    });
```

And then ActionMethod

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GeneratePass(string[] Id)
 {
     return View();
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Change your ajax code with this

```
     function SetCompanyDetailsPopUp(Email) {
     var Value = Email.value;
     debugger;
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         async: false,
         dataType: "json",
         url: "/CRMLogin/GeneratePass",
         data:'{ id:" '+ Value + ' "}',             // May be i am right, Here is problem
         success: function (result) {
             var data = '';

             alert(result);
             //alert(result);
             //alert('sucessfully generated');
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: When I put this code I am getting + value+  value at Serverside,

Comment: Not the exact value of Checkbox

Comment: `var Value = Email.value;`  here `Value` not getting email value from `Email.value`

Comment: debug and check here `var Value = Email.value;`. What you get in `Value` @Dinup

Comment: If I pass Email Directly Then Also it is not taking the value.. It is an Array is the Reason

Comment: if it is array then `public ActionResult GeneratePass(string[] id)` change your controller method parameter and then it will work fine